# HAVING() Unknown column in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this working code with `AS count` self declared field using eloquent

```
$delimeter = ' ';
$keywords = explode($delimeter, $keyword_search); 
$base_query = \DB::table('yeast_entire_search')->selectRaw('
        id,
        part_number, 
        part_name,
Round ((Char_length(Concat(
        LOWER(part_number), 
        LOWER(part_name)
    )) 
    - 
    Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(
        LOWER(part_number), 
        LOWER(part_name)

    ), LOWER("'.$keyword_search.'"), ""))) / Char_length(LOWER("'.$keyword_search.'")))  AS count 
 ');
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $base_query->where(function($query) use ($keyword){
            $query->where('part_number', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%') 
                ->orWhere('part_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    });
}
$data = $base_query->orderBy('count','DESC')->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

But when I tried to add `havingRaw()` like this

```
$data = $base_query->orderBy('count','DESC')->havingRaw(' count > 0 ')->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

But Im getting an error like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `->havingRaw('count > 0')` to `->having('count', '>' , 0)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this use `having`**

```
$data = $base_query->orderBy('count','DESC')->having('count', '>' , 0)->paginate(20);
return $data;
```

[HAVING DOCUMENTATION](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

Comment: I'm getting this kind of error when I tried your code `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'count' in 'having clause'

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom select it's self in having raw query:

```
$data = $base_query->orderBy('count','DESC')
->havingRaw('Round ((Char_length(Concat(
    LOWER(part_number), 
    LOWER(part_name)
)) 
- 
Char_length(REPLACE ( Concat(
    LOWER(part_number), 
    LOWER(part_name)
), 
LOWER("'.$keyword_search.'"), ""))) / Char_length(LOWER("'.$keyword_search.'"))) > 0 ')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: I'm getting unknown column part_number.

Answer (score -1):

typing error instead of ->havingRaw(' count > 0 ')  try ->havingRaw('count' > 0)

Comment: Tried this but got this `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: [Docs show this is clearly not correct syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw).